# Django rest framework use kwargs in serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model `Ingredient` which has ForeignKey field. I use `modelSerializer` to pass data. I'm passing `recipe_id` in url like this `recipes/{recipe.id}/ingredients`. My current solution is to modify `request.data` in the view but I'm sure if it's corrent way for such a common case.

What's the best way to pass `Recipe` to serializer?

**models.py**

```
class Ingredient(TimeStamp):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ingredients',
    )
```

**serializers.py**

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'quantity',
            'unit',
            'recipe'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
class IngredientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = IngredientSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        request.data['recipe'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to pass the serializer the context dict
you can create your own or get the default one:

```py
context = self.get_serializer_context()
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, context=context)
```

if you'll at the source code for get_serializer_context:

```py
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }
```

it adds the view class and the request to the serializer context.

in the serializer, I override the create method and pass the creation data dict the related object id.

```py
class S(ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
       validated_data['recipe_id'] = self.kwargs['pk']
       return super(S, self).create(validated_data)
```

and no need to override the create of the view